# Bind a datatable to a bootstrap table

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I want to bind a datatable to a bootstrap table. The datatable is a result of a sql query. I have seen that there are ways to do this with json. But I'm new to json and can't understand those methods. Can anyone explain how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you referring to datatables.js datetables? Or are you referring to a C# datatable?

Comment: To a C# datatable..

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use MVC,

In the **Back-end** part add:

```
string query;
SqlCommand SqlCommand;
SqlDataReader result;
int sindex=DropDownList1.SelectedIndex+1;
int hindex =DropDownList3.SelectedIndex+1;
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
//Open the connection to db
conn.Open();                
query = string.Format("select * from table where clumn='"+s+"' ", s);
SqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(query, conn);              
result = SqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

And in the **front end** part:

```
<div class="row" style="color:#ba9494;margin-top:15%;margin-left:5%">
    <div class="col-lg-2 align-center" >
          Id
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 align-center">
          Name
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 align-center">
        OtherIds
    </div> 
    <div class="col-lg-7 align-center">
        Description
    </div>

</div>

foreach (var item in result)
{
  <div class="row" style="margin-left:5%">
    <div class="col-lg-2 align-center">
           item.Id
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 align-center">
           item.Names
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 align-center">
           item.OthersId
    </div>      
    <div class="col-lg-7 align-center">
           item.Descriptions
    </div>
  </div>

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To do it without Json, you can use a DataRepeater with an item template:

```
<table>
    <asp:Repeater id="tableRepeater" runat="server" DataSourceID="TableDataSource">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td><%# Eval("TableProperty") %></td>
            </tr>
         </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:repeater>
</table>
```

You can just do the same with div or whatever you like inside the ItemTemplate, and that will be repeated for each row in the query. You can add whatever bootstrap classes you need to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

This might help to get hold of the json: [How to get SQL Server query result's data into JSON Format ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399977/how-to-get-sql-server-query-results-data-into-json-format)

Then something like this in your script?

```
    $('#elementSelector').bootstrapTable({
        data: yourDataGoesHere,
        onLoadError: function () { // deal with error },
        columns: [
            { field: 'dataFieldName', title: 'aTitle', class: 'col-md-4', sortable: true }
        ]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use json. If you are familiar with **ASP.NET MVC** then this is very simple,just make your database, import it with **models** and in your **views** just call your model and the item it contains.
**Example:**

```
@model IEnumerable<NameOfYourProject.Models.ModelResultName>

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "ABC";
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_PQR.cshtml";
}
    <div class="row" style="color:#ba9494;margin-top:15%;margin-left:5%">
      <div class="col-lg-2 align-center" >
          Id
      </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 align-center">
          Name
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 align-center">
        OtherIds
    </div> 
    <div class="col-lg-7 align-center">
        Description
    </div>

</div>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="row" style="margin-left:5%">
        <div class="col-lg-2 align-center">
               @item.Id
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 align-center">
               @item.Names
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1 align-center">
               @item.OthersId
        </div>      
        <div class="col-lg-7 align-center">
               @item.Descriptions
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

The above **@foreach** code also works for other projects besides MVC too. 
Hope you got your answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer..but the problem is I'm not familiar with MVC also.. :(

Comment: You can do similar things in web forms, just use this format instead: `<table>
  <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
    <tr><td><%= item.title %></td></tr>
  <% } %>
</table>`

Comment: the question is **by using bootstrap**